# javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException while trying to access S3 Bucket

Tags: java, scala, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3

I am trying to access a Bucket and upload/download a file from S3, I keep getting the following exception:

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 's3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com, O=Amazon.com Inc., L=Seattle, ST=Washington, C=US)

Here is my code(it is scala, but can be translated to Java):

```
val bucket = config.getString("aws.bucket").getOrElse("none")

val accessKey = config.getString("aws.accessKeyId").getOrElse("none")

val secretKey = config.getString("aws.secretKey").getOrElse("none")

val region = config.getString("aws.region").getOrElse("none")

val credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey)

val s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentials)


s3.setRegion(new com.amazonaws.regions.Region(new InMemoryRegionImpl(region, null)))

val s3Obj = s3.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucket, "test1.jpg", new File("/Users/test/Desktop/nature.jpg")))
```

Some more info: I am using latest version of the Java SDK, and I am using V4.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the SSL certificate is expecting one more level in the hostname, such as

```
myhost.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
^^^^^^^
```

where `myhost` is whatever your bucket name is.

Comment: How do I set this in the client?

Comment: If I try seting the Endpoint, instead of the region, with setEndpoint from S3Client.
    s3.setEndpoint(s"http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com")

I get Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: A0015BF9C8362F68)
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: A0015BF9C8362F68), S3 Extended Request ID: yTT6fpwrpw9VopJ0wicNFwC1q98DGGXGUZInQFTX0PL/CLalUWFlvyqjcEzKJbj3giC0XXRlys8=

Comment: SOmetimes Also getting this exception:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: hostname cannot be null
        at com.amazonaws.util.AwsHostNameUtils.parseRegion(AwsHostNameUtils.java:79)